# Problem while playing sound using AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, avaudioplayer

In my app, I am playing sound from library directory.

Here sounds are stored in different folders with different naming conventions.

For example,

Folders like : `Test` , `Test 2`

Now when I try to play sound from `Test`, it plays sound.

But when I try to play sound from `Test 2`, It is not playing any sound.

I am using following code for playing sound :

> recordFile : "/Users/taxsmart2/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/E2F2C422-605A-4EC7-A40A-7429A966351C/Library/List13-Test/rec212:13:21.caf"   // Play sound
>
> recordFile : "/Users/taxsmart2/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/E2F2C422-605A-4EC7-A40A-7429A966351C/Library/`List13-Test 2`/rec212:13:21.caf"   // Does not Playing sound

```
// May be because of space `Test 2`

AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:recordFile] error:nil];

[player prepareToPlay];
```

And on the button click I am having following code :

```
[player play];
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:recordFile]` instead of `URLWithString:`.