# Playing sound with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to play a mp3 file in objective c with Xcode for the iPhone.

In viewDidLoad:

```
 NSURL *mySoundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/mySound.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *myError;
mySound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] fileURLWithPath:heartBeatURL error:&myError];
[mySound play];
```

I found a suggestion here: [Problem while playing sound using AVAudioPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304803/problem-while-playing-sound-using-avaudioplayer)

but it did not work for me, it only generated more issues.

When the program launches I get this in output and the program crashes:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SecondViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you imported the AVFoundation framework in you ViewController header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you haven't linked the AVFoundation framework into your app.

Assuming recent enough xcode:

1. Select your project in the Project Navigator on the left
2. Select your Target
3. Select Build Phases
4. Add AVFoundation.framework to the Link Binary With Libraries phase

Here's some working AVAudioPlayer code for comparison:

```
NSURL *mySoundURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BadTouch" ofType:@"mp3"]];
NSError *myError;
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:mySoundURL error:&myError];
[self.player play];
```

Comment: Ok I did that but now I get a SIGABRT error when I click on the second tab in the simulator. It goes away when I block out the code I posted above. How do I fix this?

Comment: it's hard to say at first glance.  you're only showing a snippet of the code, and it's obviously incomplete.  why do you setup mySoundURL but play heartBeatURL?  is heartBeatURL being setup correctly?  also, AVAudioPlayer doesn't take a fileURLWithPath:error: initializer.

Answer (score 1):

Add AVFoundation.framework to your Projects Target `Link Binary With Libraries`

Then import in your .h:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

    AVAudioPlayer *player;
    }
@property (strong,nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;

@end
```

in your .m:

```
    @synthesize player;


    NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/mySound.mp3"];
    NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
    NSError* err;

    //Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

    if( err ){
        //bail!
        NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        //set our delegate and begin playback
        player.delegate = self;
        [player play];

    }
```